# how to remove negative symbol from negative y-axis on highcharts/highstock

Tags: highcharts

I want to treat the negative portion of the y-axis (below 0), as if it were above zero -- because I'm plotting something else above 0. So, basically, I want to remove the negative symbol on Highstock's negative y-axis to make it look positive, just upside down. (I'm still going to enter the data with a '-' symbol so that it gets plotted below 0, but leaving the negative symbol there would be confusing)

Also, for the tool tip, is there an easy way to, say, multiply the value by -1 so that it shows up positive as well?

Does anyone know how I might do this?

thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) function to manipulate the label appearance:

```
    yAxis: {            
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Math.abs(this.value);
            }
        }
    },
```

You can do the same for the tool tip as well:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.x + '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + Math.abs(this.y);
        }
    },
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/38WMR/).

Comment: Thank you very much -- this is exactly what I needed. For anyone that stumbles across this later, if you have more than one series, you can't call `this.series.name`, you need to call `this.points[i].series.name`. Same thing applies for multiple y values in one tooltip: `this.point[0].y` and `this.points[1].y` will get the selected y values for series 1 and 2. See [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) for more info.